# How to read data from usb hid device on android 4.0

Tags: android, usb, hid

I don't know how to read data from usb hid device on Android 4.0,I already used `HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = managerme.getDeviceList()` get this device, but I don't know how to read data from usb hid device asynchronous，please who can help me, thanks.

Comment: Try here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280581/using-android-to-communicate-with-a-usb-hid-device