# TI DLP NIRScan Nano: connect to Android smartphone via USB

Tags: android, usb, hid

I have implemented an Android app which communicates with the DLP NIRscan Nano via Bluetooth LE. It is working fine, but unfortunately it takes a long time to transfer the scan results - especially if you want to do several individual scans in a row.

That's why I'm currently trying to connect the device via an USB OTG cable to the Android smartphone. I can successfully connect to the device via USB but it is unclear how to read or write data.

What I have understood so far:

- the device provides two endpoints: one with IN direction and one with OUT direction.
- both endpoints have interrupt type, that's why I need to communicate asynchronously (see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbRequest.html) by using queue() and requestWait() methods.
- based on the documentation the device is using HID 1.1 to exchange commands. An example project would be the Missile Launcher: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_development/blob/master/samples/USB/MissileLauncher/src/com/android/missilelauncher/MissileLauncherActivity.java which is using

  - `UsbRequest#queue()`
  - `sendCommand()` which is calling `mConnection.controlTransfer(0x21, 0x9, 0x200, 0, message, message.length, 0);`
  - `requestWait()` to wait until a response is available.
    But this is not working as well. Also changing the sendCommand to 
    `int transfer = mConnectionRead.controlTransfer(0xA1, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, message, message.length, 0);` doesn't work (transfer = -1), see [Using Android to Communicate with a USB HID Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280581/using-android-to-communicate-with-a-usb-hid-device)

When I want to read e.g. the Tiva version information, I thought it will work like the code mentioned below.
The specification of the device: http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/dlpu030g/dlpu030g.pdf see page 83

**Why is it not working? I never get any response from the sensor.**

Do I have to use controlTransfer? Is the data packet wrong? Is it possible at all to connect the scanner via USB to an Android smartphone?

Any help appreciated :-)

Thanks
Ben

```
UsbConfiguration usbConfiguration = usbDevice.getConfiguration(0);
UsbInterface usbInterface = usbConfiguration.getInterface(0);
inEndpoint = usbInterface.getEndpoint(0);
outEndpoint = usbInterface.getEndpoint(1);
connection = usbManager.openDevice(usbDevice);
connection.claimInterface(usbInterface, true);

byte[] data = new UsbPacket()
        .setGroupByte((byte) 0x02)
        .setCommandByte((byte) 0x16)
        .setFlagRW(UsbPacket.RW.READ)
        .setFlagReady(UsbPacket.READY.READY)
        .toByteArray();

UsbRequest request = new UsbRequest();
request.initialize(connection, outEndpoint);
request.queue(ByteBuffer.wrap(data), data.length);
connection.requestWait();

UsbRequest request1 = new UsbRequest();
request1.initialize(connection, inEndpoint);
byte[] result = new byte[28];
request1.queue(ByteBuffer.wrap(result), result.length);
connection.requestWait(); // Actual: never terminates!
// Expected: result byte array contains Tiva version information



class UsbPacket {
    private byte flags;
    private int sequence = 0;
    private byte commandByte;
    private byte groupByte;
    private byte[] data;

    enum RW {
        WRITE,
        READ
    }

    enum READY {
        BUSY,
        READY
    }

    enum ERROR {
        SUCCESS,
        ERROR,
        BUSY
    }

    UsbPacket setFlagRW(RW flag) {
        if (flag == RW.READ) {
            this.flags = (byte) (this.flags | 0x80);
        }
        return this;
    }

    UsbPacket setFlagReady(READY flag) {
        if (flag == READY.READY) {
            this.flags = (byte) (this.flags | 0x40);
        }
        return this;
    }

    UsbPacket setFlagError(ERROR flag) {
        if (flag == ERROR.ERROR) {
            this.flags = (byte) (this.flags | 0x20);
        }
        if (flag == ERROR.BUSY) {
            this.flags = (byte) (this.flags | 0x10);
        }
        return this;
    }

    UsbPacket setSequence(int sequence) {
        if (0 > sequence || sequence > 255) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only values from 0 to 255 are allowed");
        }
        this.sequence = sequence;
        return this;
    }

    UsbPacket setCommandByte(byte commandByte) {
        this.commandByte = commandByte;
        return this;
    }

    UsbPacket setGroupByte(byte groupByte) {
        this.groupByte = groupByte;
        return this;
    }

    public UsbPacket setData(byte[] data) {
        this.data = data;
        return this;
    }

    byte[] toByteArray() {
        byte[] dataLength;
        int lengthOfCommandBytes = 2;
        if (data != null) {
            dataLength = ConvertUtility.convertTo2ByteArray(lengthOfCommandBytes + data.length);
        }
        else {
            dataLength = ConvertUtility.convertTo2ByteArray(lengthOfCommandBytes);
        }
        byte[] header = new byte[] {
                0x00,
                flags,
                (byte) sequence,
                dataLength[0],
                dataLength[1],
                commandByte,
                groupByte
        };

        byte[] packet;
        if (data != null) {
            packet = new byte[7 + data.length];
            System.arraycopy(header, 0, packet, 0, header.length);
            System.arraycopy(data, 0, packet, 7, data.length);
        }
        else {
            packet = header;
        }
        return packet;
    }
}
```